# ¿Cómo pasar una variable de javascript (dentro de una funcion) a php para una consulta?

Tags: javascript, php

Quisiera saber como puedo pasar una variable a php, ya que en mi codigo de javascript, tengo una funcion, donde hago una consulta e imprimo los que coincidan, pero quisiera saber como puedo pasar la variable en ese mismo momento:

```
?php 
    $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','agenda');  
?>

<script>

    function DayMenu(i){

    var JS_day = i;
    //Esta es la variable que quiero usar abajo en la consulta del php
        
        <?php
 
              $consulta = "SELECT * FROM citas WHERE fecha LIKE '2021-07-22'";
        
        ?>


    
    }
<script>
```

Puse mi codigo así, solo para que se den una idea de como es la estructura, pues tengo todo en el mismo archivo (html, abajo el script y ahi mismo las consultas de php)

Quisiera saber como pudiera pasar esa variable entera JS_day en la funcion a php para usarla en el select así:

```
$day = JS_day;
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM citas WHERE fecha LIKE '2021-07-$day'";
```

Comment: Las variables de JS sólo existen en el lado cliente. Si deseas enviar un valor al servidor, debes usar una llamada Ajax.

Comment: Hola, si, eso vi en algunos lados que la solucion es usando Ajax, pero no entiendo muy bien como se usa o como podría implementarlo ahí. He visto que usan ajax pero llamando a algun archivo en php, y no entiendo como sería en mi caso.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varias opciones

**Asignar el valor de la variable a un elemento input oculto**

Esta opción es la mas común la única desventaja es que solo la podrás obtener mediante un POST

```html
<script>
   DayMenu("lunes");

   function DayMenu(i){

      var JS_day = i;
      //Esta es la variable que quiero usar abajo en la consulta del php
      document.getElementById("txtvalor")=JS_day;
    
    }
</script>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text" id="txtvalor" name="txtvalor" />
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="btnenviar"/>
</form>
```

**Mediante Ajax**

Aquí necesitaras Jquery

```html
 function DayMenu(i){
         var url = "direccion a un archivo php;
         $.ajax({
             type:"POST",
             url:url,
             data:{
                 JS_day:i,
             },
             success:function(result){
                 console.log(result);
             }
         })  
        
  }
  
  
  //Luego en el documento php 
  
  <?php 
    echo $_POST['JS_day'];
  ?>
```

Hay mas opciones  como utilizar una `cookie`, pasar el parámetro por `url` pero esas dos son las mas utilizadas ya que no recargan la pagina

Comment: Hola. Muchas Gracias por responder. Efectivamente traté con cookie y funcionaba pero solo al recargar la página, y esque la funcion que tengo ahi en javascript, es de un calendario, y se ejecuta cada que dan click a un número de día, abriendo el menú de ese día y la variable i tomaría un numero entero de 1-30. Quería saber como hacer para que cada que se ejecute la funcion, esa variable entera i pueda pasarse a php y se ejecute la consulta con esa variable. Trataré de implementarlo así en mi codigo